# Using install_github is it necessary to create the documentation first for the NAMESPACE to be correct?

Tags: r, git, package

The title was long, and really said all I had to say.  But when making an R package and putting it on github, is it necessary to build the roxygen documentation prior to pushing to github?  Otherwise, I seem to have problems when using `devtools::install_github` because the NAMESPACE isn't being built correctly (if the docs havent already been built).  I am asking because it would be nice to not have to store all the .Rd files in each repository, but instead build them during install.  Am I missing something here?  Plus, everytime they are rebuilt the `.git` folder gets bigger and bigger.

This confused me for a while because I had functions I was exporting (`@export`), but hadn't build the documentation and didn't realize that was necessary.

Comment: `devtools:::source_pkg` got a `before_install` parameter that accepts a function. You could probably pass `roxygenize` to it via the ellipses. Can't test since you don't provide a test case.

Comment: At a second glance, you can't. The ellipses unfortunately is not passed to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it necessary to build the roxygen documentation prior to pushing to github

Yes. The documentation, a NAMESPACE file, these are all part of a complete, installable package.

> it would be nice to not have to store all the .Rd files in each repository, but instead build them during install

This would assume that everyone uses `roxygen2` to build .Rd files, but `roxygen` is a relatively recent development and is not required - it used to be common to write `.Rd` files by hand (*::shudder::*).

It should also be expected that documentation files are viewed and tested by the package author - if you don't build them yourself you're probably including all sorts of typos or even bugs that prevent them from building at all. You should be `check`ing your package as well, even if it's not destined for CRAN. Not doing so means you're putting up untested, likely shoddy and buggy code.

.Rd files are tiny, just put them in your repo.